# Postgres: JOIN between JSON value and TEXT

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to make a join on 2 tables. The value I am trying to join is stored in a JSON column on one table and in a TEXT column in the other. Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT inv.data -> 'total_amount' as iTotalAmount, 
   inv.data -> 'due_date' as iDueDate,
   inv.data -> 'emission_date' as iEmissionDate,
   inv.data -> 'customer_name' as iCustomerName, 
   matc.ch_number as mCompanyHouseNumber,
   matc.acc_software_company_name as mAccSoftName
   FROM invoices inv, matching_ch_acc_software matc
   JOIN mCompanyHouseNumber on iCustomerName
   WHERE inv.rating_data IS NOT null
```

I am however getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "mcompanyhousenumber" does not exist Position: 363
```

I assumed you cant use values defined in the query as part of the JOIN condition? What would be a walk around?

**EDIT**

updated query:

```
SELECT inv.data -> 'total_amount' as iTotalAmount, 
   inv.data -> 'due_date' as iDueDate,
   inv.data -> 'emission_date' as iEmissionDate,
   inv.data -> 'customer_name' as iCustomerName, 
   matc.ch_number as mCompanyHouseNumber,
   matc.acc_software_company_name as mAccSoftName
   FROM invoices inv, matching_ch_acc_software matc
   INNER JOIN matching_ch_acc_software
   ON (invoices.data -> 'customer_name')::text =  matching_ch_acc_software.acc_software_company_name
   WHERE inv.rating_data IS NOT null
```

error:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "invoices" Hint: There is an entry for table "inv", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. Position: 397
```

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit joins, switch to explicit joins everywhere.

Comment: Do you have a table mcompanyhousenumber???

Comment: @jarlh sorry that is my mistake i pasted the wrong query. I have now eddited the post above

Comment: Explicit `JOIN`'s are evaluated before implicit, comma separated joins. I.e. the `ON` clause above doesn't know about the invoices table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query text is mangled enough that I can't even figure out what the intention of it is.  You are joining 3 things, one of which seems to be a alias to a column, not a table.

You cannot use select-list aliases in your join condition.  You need to refer to the columns/expressions explicitly.

```
ON table1.text_column = table2.json_column->>'thing'
```

Based on your edit, I think I can see the intention there.

You are joining to matching_ch_acc_software twice, but apparently without meaning to.  You are joining it to itself with INNER JOIN, and to the other table with `,`.  Since explicit joins are tighter than commas, at the point it is evaluating the inner join the invoices table is not yet "available", which is why you get the error message you do.  Also, once you assign an alias to a table, you must reference columns with that alias, not with the original table name.

Finally, `(invoices.data -> 'customer_name')::text` means the same thing as `invoices.data->>'customer_name'`, but is uglier.

```
SELECT inv.data -> 'total_amount' as iTotalAmount, 
   inv.data -> 'due_date' as iDueDate,
   inv.data -> 'emission_date' as iEmissionDate,
   inv.data -> 'customer_name' as iCustomerName, 
   matc.ch_number as mCompanyHouseNumber,
   matc.acc_software_company_name as mAccSoftName
   FROM invoices inv INNER JOIN matching_ch_acc_software matc
   ON inv.data ->> 'customer_name' =  matc.acc_software_company_name
   WHERE inv.rating_data IS NOT null ;
```